# GMAIl API: how to get messages without any prompting for authorization?

Tags: gmail-api, google-workspace

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java

there is guide that`s describes only the way to get messages with authorization prompt.

> The first time you run the sample, it prompts you to authorize access:
> If you're not already signed in to your Google Account, sign in when prompted. If you're signed in to multiple accounts, select one account to use for authorization.
> Click Accept.

Can we call it without any prompt, just using some kind of a token and if yes, than how to do it?
Goal: to run automated tests locally and remotely and check one specific gmail for letters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access Gmail on behalf of users on your domain then you should look into using a service account instead.

You can delegate your script to that of a user on the domain and it will be able to impersonate them.  This means you wont need any user prompt for authorization.

[delegate_settings](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/delegate_settings)

they don't appear to have a java sample there you may have to look around. I can tell you it works i created something for a client once.